# Copy files to all subdirectories

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I was planning on using a command like this

```
FOR /R %f in (".") DO xcopt test.txt %f
```

to copy a file into all subdirectories of a folder.

This works fine when I write the file into the command prompt but it doesn't work when I put it into a batch file and run the batch file.

Any ideas as to why this wouldn't run from a batch file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably to do with your `%f` in a batch file these should be `%%f`. This is to do with the way variable expansion is performed in batch files.

Comment: yip that was the problem cheers for that

Answer (score 1):

```
for /?
```

brings up the help. The first paragraph of text mentions:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable. ...

Comment: good tip, but this would be better left as a comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe. I think it is useful information in its own right that could be missed if it were provided in a comment. I'll delete the reference to Martin's answer to remove the discussion feel of my answer.